# SQL Dense Rank with Case When

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple SQL line that tells me all the orders over a certain time range. We define customers by their email.

```
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN T.Order_Status <> 'CANCELLED' AND T.Date_Created BETWEEN '6/02/2019' and '8/02/2019'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) over (partition by Email) TotalOrdersNewBase
```

Now what I want to do is find a way to get all customers over a certain range.

This line tells me all the customers per month over my whole period

```
,DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Date order by Email asc) + DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Date order by Email desc) - 1 as TotalCustomers
```

But how do I format that above line to be only between 6/02 and 8/02 ?

Comment: Note that `DENSE_RANK()` will not give you the `count` of customers.

Comment: whats wrong with using a where clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intention of this code is to count the number of unique emails during a period of time.  For the overall number, the correct code is:

```
(dense_rank() over (order by Email asc) +
 dense_rank() over (order by Email desc) - 1
) as TotalCustomers
```

Within a period of time, I think this works:

```
(dense_rank() over (order by (case when t.Date_Created >= '2019-06-02' and t.date_created < '2019-08-03' then Email end) asc) +
 dense_rank() over (order by (case when t.Date_Created >= '2019-06-02' and t.date_created < '2019-08-03' then Email end) desc) - 1
) as TotalCustomers_in_period
```

Actually, "think" is a little weak.  This is the right logic.  The only concern are some boundary issues and subtracting out the `NULL` email (so there might be an off-by-one issue in some edge cases).

Answer (score 1):

The below statement should work:

```
,CASE WHEN Date between '06-01-2002' and '08-31-2002' then DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Date order by Email asc) else 0 end + 
CASE WHEN Date between '06-01-2002' and '08-31-2002' then DENSE_RANK() over (partition by Date order by Email desc) - 1 else 0 end as TotalCustomers
```

Note: I have assumed the dates have to be restricted between Jun 2002 and Aug 2002

Comment: I understand the attempt, but the upvote does baffle me.